# Phonegap 3.0 iOS Generic Push Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

I am trying to make a phonegap 3.0 application with push notifications but cannot get the plugin that everywhere is telling me to use to work. It is the generic push plugin here: http://phonegap.com/blog/build/introducing-genericpush-plugin/

I have added the javascript to the index but when i try and run the .register function it does not work.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that this plugin is not yet ready for Phonegap 3.  I'd suggest you use Phonegap 2.9 until it is.

As you are running with iOS, I'd recommend you follow this tutorial:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap.html

and for help setting up your push settings in the app itself use this one:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Don't forget, that you have to use the app on a real device, as push notifications don't work in the emulator.